# How to save several pieces of information from a JavaFX form to a File

Tags: list, file, javafx

I can not seem to figure out how to store the data in the TextFields in a text file using JavaFX and accepting a certain number of entries. For example: One would fill out the form 3times and all of those 3 pieces of information would be in the txt file. How would I implement an ArrayList into the method in order to display?

I have already tried to implement a String ArrayList but it does not display the data in the TextFields when I press "Save Information", all that displays is `[, , , ]`

```java
    public void saveInfo(ActionEvent e) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        File fileIt = new File("InfoGathered.txt");

        try {
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(fileIt);

            for (int i = 0; i < ; i++) {
                String s1 = new String();
output.println(tfFirstName.getText() + tfLastName.getText() + tfdBirth.getText() + tfEmpID.getText());
                list.add(s1);

            }
            output.write(list.toString());
            output.close();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I am expecting the TextFields to appear within the File such as `[Sam Smith 12/03/94 123-AB, Lena Smith 12/12/91 127-AB, Sam Smith 02/18/95 726-HF ]`

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things fundamentally wrong in your code, I do not even know where to start. But if it is the solution you want for your given problem, below code will write the text of TextFields to the file in your desired format.

```
public void saveInfo(ActionEvent e) {
    File fileIt = new File("InfoGathered.txt");
    try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(fileIt)){
        String outString = tfFirstName.getText() + " "
                + tfLastName.getText() + " "
                + tfdBirth.getText() + " "
                + tfEmpID.getText();
        output.write(outString);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps with displaying it in the file but what I was trying to do is get several entries into the file, which is why I had a for loop and the ArrayList

Comment: So, you edited your question. You question is still not clear. What do you mean by "One would fill out the form 3times ". Do they press some kind of button 3 times with 3 new information?

Comment: Yeah, there's a "Save Information" button and a "Clear All" button, once having put data into the TextFields the Save Information button should be pressed and then the Clear All button will clear them so that the process can be done again